# How to retrieve last primary Id from mdb's table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access

I got table with next columns: `Id, Name, Age, Class`

I am trying to insert new row in db like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Age, Class)
VALUES (@name, @age, @class)
```

And get an exeption:

```
"Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value."
```

The question is how to add a new row without knowing next primary Id, or maybe there is a way to get this Id from the table with the help of another query ?

Comment: I think you forgot to set the `id` field as `IDENTITY`.  Please can you include the *complete* table definition?

Comment: @Dems, do you mean to change the type of `Id` column from Number to AutoNumber ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the data type of ID column to AutoNumber instead of Integer.

Comment: So far, this seems to be the only relevant answer.

Comment: Once the data type is properly set, @@identity will work against the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Access, but the MySQL syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Name, Age, Class) VALUES (NULL, @name, @age, @class);
```

Comment: This is not suitable for MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id,Name, Age, Class)
 VALUES ((select max(id)+1 from MyTable),@name, @age, @class)
```

Comment: Using max to get the last ID is a *really* bad idea in anything but a single user system.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the "id" column as Auto number in the Mytable and then try

OR else

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id,Name, Age, Class)
select max(id)+1,@name, @age, @class FROM MyTable
```

Comment: As I said above, max is a **really** bad idea.

Comment: Then make the ID Column as Auto number